# posts not showing on index.php

Tags: posts, templates, page-template, frontpage

[Live site.](http://parlourdc.com)

I've got a custom theme, wherein the homepage(front-page.php) is static and the "posts" page is Press(index.php). Everything with the theme works great, with the exception of the posts not showing when viewing the Press page- it shows the homepage content instead.

In the Reading settings, I have A Static Page: Front Page is Home(front-page.php) / Posts Page is Press(index.php).

Here's what I'm using for index.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="logo">
    <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/parlour_side.png" alt="Parlour Salon logo" id="logo" /></a>
</div><!-- end logo -->

<div id="main">
    <div class="content">
        <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <?php the_content('read more...'); ?>
            <p><?php the_date(); ?></p>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php else : ?>
                <p>I'm not sure what you're looking for.</p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div><!-- end content -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Any ideas what could be causing the issue? I'm sure it's something simple, I've just been working on this for so long I need fresh eyes. Thanks.

**ETA:** Also, for what it's worth, I've just noticed that style.css doesn't seem to be working in Safari. This didn't happen until I added the Press page and subsequent changes.

Answer (score 4):

The template naming is a bit confusing in this situation, but what is happening is normal behavior in the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

`home.php` shows your posts page, whether it's on the front page, or assigned to another page when using a static front page. If you want your `home.php` template to be used for your static front page, rename it `front-page.php`. In the absence of a `home.php` template, your posts page (Press) will use the `index.php` template.

Answer (score 0):

rename ***home.php*** to something else, possibly to ***front-page.php***;

***home.php*** is a reserved file name for the posts page -

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I've renamed home.php to front-page.php, the problem persists. Also, for what it's worth, switching to the Twenty Eleven theme allowed for the Press page to work properly.